# problem in the program looping only 1 as output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float root;
    int i=1,sum;
    do {
        sum = 2*i - 1;
        printf("\t%d\n",sum);
        i *= 5 / 3;
    } while (sum <= 1.5);
    root = sqrt(i) ;
    printf("\n%.3f",root);
    return 0;
}
```

It only repeats 1.

I tried to get numbers like 1, 3, 7, or 15, but I only got repeats of 1.

Comment: `5/3` is `1` because it's integer division, so `i *= 5/3` the same as `i *= 1`, which doesn't change `i`.

Comment: Oh I see "looping only 1 as output", as in "looping endlessly while only outputting 1 forever....". Not as in "looping only once".

Comment: What exactly is the program supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

If `i` is really supposed to be a power of 5/3, then it needs to be a `double`, not an `int`. (There's not much point to using `float`, so make `root` a `double` as well.)

Since you want to compare it to 1.5, `sum` should also be a `double`. However `sum` is not a sum! Maybe you meant `sum += 2*i - 1;`? In that case, `sum` needs to be initialized to zero.

And then you don't show the sum?

What are you trying to calculate?

Answer (score 1):

5/3 = 1.66666666667. However, both i and 5/3 are of the integer type, so instead of 1.66666666667, it only shows the integer part of that number which is 1. To fix this, make i either a float or an double and replace 5/3 with 5.0/3.0

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are floating point, therefore you should declare your variables as a floating point type `double`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  double root;
  double i = 1, sum;
  do {
    sum = 2 * i - 1;
    printf("\t%lf\n", sum);    // use %lf for printing doubles
    i *= 5.0 / 3.0;            // 5/3 is a integer division resulting in 1
  } while (sum <= 1.5);
  root = sqrt(i);
  printf("\n%.3lf", root);     // use %lf for printing doubles
  return 0;
}
```

One possible output will be:

```
        1.000000
        2.333333

1.667
```

OTOH I'm not sure what the program is supposed to do.